# How to set two requirements for a single question in Google Form?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms, google-form-quiz

I am trying to gather and combine the sales requirement data in google sheet. To collect the data I am using Google Forms. In question number 2, I need name of the product which I will get from dropdown menu and just beside the cell of product name, in the same row, I need amount of the product which will be filled manually. but I can not set two requirement in the same question.

Can you please share any idea to solve it out?
Thanks.

Comment: If you have custom requirements, then write a custom HTML form

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.